# Should you install GPU drivers on HDD or SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, drivers, ssd, performance, display-driver

I have always been wondering the following questions:

- Where should the GPU drivers be installed? HDD or SSD?
- How often are they read?
- Does it need to be fast?
- Is there any performance gain when they are installed on a SSD?

If they are often read, it needs to be fast and / or there are performance gains (so, if there is any advantage in installing them on a SSD):

- Is it worth the number of readings, that would reduce the SSD's lifetime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not worry about this at all, because the only thing you can influence is the location of accompanying utilities like catalyst control center or nVidia control panel. The actual driver files which are used to control the hardware are always put in Windows folder and they are loaded into memory when the pc runs so it does not matter where they are. The biggest speedup you can have is to install OS or the games you frequently play on a fastest available drive so the pc boots faster and the games load quicker.